# Optimize an Update query using IN subquery on Self

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 80000 row database with a result number between 130000000 and 168000000, the results are paired using field pid. I need to change the status of the rows from 'G' to 'X' where the result pair has a difference of 4300000.

I have come up with the query below, which works but is very slow, can it be improved for speed?

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 'X'
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT a.id AS id FROM table1 a, table1 b
    WHERE a.result = b.result + 4300000
    AND a.pid = b.pid
    AND a.result between 130000000 and 168000000
    AND a.status = 'G'
    ) AS c
);
```

The indexes are:-

```
table1  0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   80233   NULL    NULL        BTREE
table1  1   id  1       id  A   80233   NULL    NULL        BTREE
table1  1   id  2   result  A   80233   NULL    NULL        BTREE
table1  1   id  3   status  A   80233   4   NULL    YES BTREE
table1  1   id  4   name    A   80233   32  NULL        BTREE
table1  1   id  5    pid    A   80233   16  NULL        BTREE
```

Comment: I would start by using a proper JOIN syntax

Comment: Besides what Riggs said, also inform what all indexes are defined on the table1 ?

Comment: Would create an index on `pid`

Comment: I have an index that includes pid, result and status

Comment: What else does the index include? Can you give details about your indexes in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a subquery inside the `IN(..)` clause is generally inefficient in MySQL. Instead, you can rewrite the Update query utilizing `UPDATE .. JOIN` syntax and utilize "self-join" as well:

```
UPDATE table1 AS a 
JOIN table1 AS b 
  ON b.pid = a.pid 
     AND b.result = a.result - 4300000 
SET a.status = 'X'
WHERE a.result between 130000000 and 168000000 
  AND a.status = 'G'
```

For good performance (and if I understand [NLJ (Nested-Loop-Join)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html) correctly), you would need two indexes: `(status,result)` and `(pid)`.

First (composite) index will be used to consider rows from the table alias `a`. Since we have range condition on `result`, it will be better to define `status` first, otherwise MySQL would simply stop at the `result` field in the index (if defined first), due to range condition.

Second index will be used for lookups in the Joined table alias `b`, using [NLJ algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html).

Comment: I have added the current indexes to the question, I'll give your answer a try, thanks

Comment: I think this has fixed it, I used this query and indexes and it seems super fast, thanks so much!